# AlamofireJson/EVReflection - NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type in

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Also asked this question as a bug inside the GitHub of the project: https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects/issues/24

Using frameworks:
Alamofire (for REST)
AlamofireJsonToObjects (to deserialize the JSON)
(which relies on EVReflection)

I'm having an issue when trying to get an array of objects inside an an object to deserialize.  The output is saying `fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type` and then the debugger breaks on line 560 of EVReflection.swift `mi = Mirror(reflecting: theValue)` with the error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

It's been able to deserialize nested objects when its not in an array, so not sure what the issue might be here.  I'll paste some code below though so you can see my process.

Alamofire Request, the error happens when I ask it to print the debugDescription

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://server.com/api/get/all", headers: getAuthenticationHeaders()).
validate().
responseArray { (response: Result<[MyPrimaryObject], NSError>) in
       if(response.isSuccess){
           print(response.debugDescription)
           success(response.value)
       }
       if(response.isFailure){
           let error : NSError = response.error!
           NSLog("API failure: \(error.debugDescription)")
           failure(error)
       }
   }
```

Models:

```
public class MyPrimaryObject : EVObject{

    public var myPrimaryObjectId : NSUUID?
    public var name : String = ""
    public var myObjectDescription: String?

    public var numberOfOccurrences : Int = 0
    public var positiveResponsePercentage : Float = 0

    public var secondaryObjects : [MySecondaryObject]?

    override public func propertyMapping() -> [(String?, String?)] {
        return [("myObjectDescription","Description")]

    }
}

public class MySecondaryObject : EVObject {
    public var mySecondaryObjectId : Int = 0
    public var dateRecorded : NSDate?
    public var rating : Int = 0
    public var userRemarks : String?
}
```

It also should be noted that `MyPrimaryObject` is parsed perfectly when the `secondaryObjects` are null from the API response.

I've obviously simplified, I'm happy to share the actual code with you privately.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I reported in
https://github.com/evermeer/AlamofireJsonToObjects/issues/24

The issue was that when you have a sub object array the pascal casing conversion did not work for getting the correct type. because of this the dictionary was put in the array and you would get the error that you got.

The fix has been published in EVReflection 2.38.3